# CppUTest override header file

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, cpputest

I am learning unit testing. I can compile simply programs with Eclipse and CppUTEST. It works. Howover I have problem to understaned how to override/stub headers files. I came up with a test scenario,

My files:

```
/src:
---------- src.c src.h //native compilator, for example stm-gcc
/test:
---------- AllTests.cpp Test_src.cpp //test compilator, for example gcc
/mocks:
---------- fsrc.h fsrc.c //fake file, should override src.h
```

Theoretically, in file "src.h" are stored settings for native compiller (stm-gcc). My test compiler (gcc) cannot use these dependencies, so I should override/stub this header file. That is why I create /mocks/fsrc.h file. fsrc.h should override/stub src.h file.

Example files code:

AllTests:

```
#include "CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h"
#include "CppUTestExt/MockSupport.h"

#include <src/src.h> // -> should read the "fsrc" file instead "src"

int main(int ac, char** av) { return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac, av); }
```

Test_src.cpp

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"
#include <src.h>

class ClassName { int a; };

TEST_GROUP(ClassName)
{
  ClassName* className;

  void setup() { className = new ClassName(); }
  void teardown() { delete className; }
};

TEST(ClassName, Create)
{
  CHECK(0 != className);
  STRCMP_EQUAL(myString, "my_string_from_mock_header"); // --> myString macro should be read from "mocks/fsrc" not from "src/src.h"   
}
```

mocks/fsrc.h

```
#ifndef SRC_SRC_H_
#define SRC_SRC_H_

#define myString "mocks/Header"
int fun();

#endif /* SRC_SRC_H_ */
```

mocks/fsrc.c

```
#include "fsrc.h"    
int fun() { return 999; }
```

src/src.h

```
#ifndef SRC_SRC_H_
#define SRC_SRC_H_

#define myString "src/Header"
int fun();

#endif /* SRC_SRC_H_ */
```

src/src.c

```
#include "src.h"  
int fun() { return 1; }
```

Eclipse erorr:

'g++ -I"C:\cygwin64\home\karb\cpputest\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"AllTests.d" -MT"AllTests.o" -o "AllTests.o" "../AllTests.cpp"
../AllTests.cpp:5:10: fatal error: src/src.h: No such file or directory'

When i change:

```
include <src/src.h> to include "src/src.h"
```

compilation works, but then overwriting header files does not work. What am I doing wrong that I can't overwrite the main header file?

Comment: Why are you trying to use renamed header files? From my understanding, your header files need to have the same name, and when you are building the unit test. Build the executable using the fake header files, rather than native compilation files.